# offset datetime with each other - Must tell the number of days in total

Tags: c#, datetime

I must have built up such that I have a datetime which gets added antale day as it should go forward. and then I have time as it should set off in relation to 04/10/16 to 10/09/16

I do not care about the time which is in datetime. It should not I use for anything. What I need out of this is exactly how many days there are from that time.

```
Datetime dateString = "4/10/2016 8:30:52" //I pretend that it comes from the database, it was more in terms of see what come there.
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5);
```

What I need out of this is that it tell me how many days there are in between the two datetime as I entered.

Comment: *how many days there are in between the two datetime* there is only *one* `DateTime` there - the other is a string.

Comment: @Plutonix I pretend that it comes from the database, it was more in terms of see what come there.

Comment: all the major databases can store and return DateTimes.  given 2 DateTime values, just subtract

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can substract `DateTime` objects to obtain a `TimeSpan`:

```
Datetime dateString = DateTime.Parse("4/10/2016 8:30:52");
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan duration = dt-dateString;
```

From the `TimeSpan` object, you can get how many (full) days with :

```
int totalCompleteDays = (int)duration.TotalDays;
```

Or if you want a rounded results :

```
int roundedTotalDays = (int)Math.Round(duration.TotalDays);
```

Comment: This will work, *but be careful...* it will round the number of days without any warning. meaning that a little more than 3 and a half days is returned as 4 entire days! ;)

Comment: True @timothy-Groote. I assumed that was what the author wanted, but I may effectively be wrong. I update the answer ;)

Comment: It's fine, i think that's what he wanted too.

Comment: @BaptisteChardon but its make `-2` example, i will not have `-`

Comment: @j-petersen I didn't get what you meant by "its make -2 example". You mean a negative TimeSpan duration?

Answer (score 2):

DateTime objects support basic operators and will return `TimeSpan` objects.

```
DateTime DateTimeB = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5);
DateTime DateTimeA = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan difference = DateTimeA - DateTimeB;
```

...
you can then use the `TotalDays` [property of the timeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totaldays(v=vs.110).aspx).
...

```
Console.out.WriteLine(difference.TotalDays);
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand my problem. this is how I want antale of days out of it and not timespan of it.

Comment: I think you misread my answer then, because i'm explaining how to get the number of days out of that timespan ;)

Comment: Oohh okay :) Now I understand it better now, after it has been correct

Comment: Thanks for help i hope u will giv me +1

Comment: @J.Petersen i did, someone else downvoted on your question though.